# Cronjobs: Is there a way to set scope of shell variables only once for all cronjobs?

Tags: shell, cron, cron-task

I'm wondering if there is an more elegant solution by defining the scope of my shell variables only once? (`export QUERY_STRING;`)

Here are a couple of my crontasks, notice that I'm currently exporting each shell variable for each task:

```
2 0 1 * * QUERY_STRING='drink/beer/carlsberg'; export QUERY_STRING; /usr/local/bin/php -e /home/myuserdir/public_html/index.php
4 0 1 * * QUERY_STRING='food/pizza/hawai'; export QUERY_STRING; /usr/local/bin/php -e /home/myuserdir/public_html/index.php
```

Comment: You can write it once, at the top of crontab file.

Comment: fedorqui: I thought cronjob/task had a limited environment, hence the reason to export the shell var for each job/task. I'll try what you suggest though and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `env(1)`:

```
env QUERY_STRING=food/pizza/hawai /usr/local/bin/php -e /home/myuserdir/public_html/index.php
```

Or the short form of `export`:

```
export QUERY_STRING=food/pizza/hawai; /usr/local/bin/php -e /home/myuserdir/public_html/index.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I used the short form of export earlier - and that didn't work for me as a crontask (however it works when manually called). I expect that env might also have similar issues?

Comment: @am_ `env` is a separate program while `export` is a shell built-in, so I wouldn't expect similar issues. Try it.

Comment: That makes sense! thank you, using env works great - and are indeed shorter and more elegant. :)